# How to reverse the effect of burning an effigy

Tags: dark-souls-2

I accidentially burned a human effigy in a bonfire, thinking it would reverse hollowing. Instead it cut me off from all invasions and co-operative online play. There is now a status symbol below the stamina bar with a crossed white sign soapstone.

Is there any way to reverse this effect? Is there an item to do this, does it wear off automatically after a cetain amount of time or is there any other requirement like killing the area boss?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The effect isn't permanent, and should wear off after about half an hour. As for reversing your hollowed status, you should simply use the Human Effigy, not burn it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the reddit comment is wrong. The bone of order doesn't do this. I have used it while under the effect and got the message that it can't be used at the time. Looking at the item description revealed that the bone of order is used to reset a penalty for cutting the internet connection during an invasion. http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Bone+of+Order I guess most people only read the short "restore online functions" description and not the whole text. I can confirm though that the effect wore off automatically after about half an hour of time spent playing.